# JQuery setTimeOut while loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, settimeout, infinite-loop

My brain its going to explode.. why this dont work? im trying to animate a few divs with time interval and trying to write less code but this dont work

```
    var cargaCont = function(){
        o = 1;
        var animacion = function(i){
            $('#page2txt'+i).animate({
                height:'20'
            },200,function(){
                $('#page2img'+i).animate({
                    left:'0',
                    right:'0'
                },200,function(){
                    i++;
                    return i;
                });
            });
        }
        while(o < 3){
            setTimeout(function(){o = animacion(o);},200);
        }   
    }
```

Comment: can you post the markup? and explain what is the desired effect? there are many unnecessary lines in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this code:

```
while(o < 3){
    setTimeout(function(){o = animacion(o);},200);
}
```

is by the time the functions delayed by `setTimeout` are executed, `o` is already 3 and therefore all calls to `animacion` pass 3 instead of 1 and 2.

To circumvent this problem, you should "localize" the value of `o` by using an immediate function.

```
while(o < 3){
    //o out here is from cargaCont
    (function(o){
        //override o by naming the passed variable o
        setTimeout(function(){
            o = animacion(o); //now o refers to the local o
        },200);
    }(o)); //execute inner function, passing in o
}
```

This makes the `o` used by the functions in `setTimeout`to be bound to the `o` of the local function and not the `o` of the `cargaCont` function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what exactly you're going for but, I'm going to guess that you basically want to loop through some animations, maybe like this:

```
var cargaCont = function(){
    var i = 1,
        animacion = function(i){
            $('#page2txt'+i).animate({
               height:'20'
           },200,function(){
               $('#page2img'+i).animate({
                   left:'0',
                   right:'0'
               },200,function(){
                   if(i < 3){
                      animacion(++i);
                   }
               });
           });
       };
    animacion(i);
};
```

Edit as you feel fit or post some markup to explain further.

Cheers.